# Ошибка при добавлении в корзину "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()"

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

> https://iscarbox.ru/ - сайт Ошибка в том что при добавлении товара в
> корзину у меня выходит ошибка сервера 500, использую ajax код -
> main.js
>
> > ```
> > $(document).ready(function(){
> >     function basketUpdating(product_id, quantity, product_material, product_thread, product_border, product_accessory){
> >         var data = {};
> >         data.product_id = product_id;
> >         data.quantity = quantity;
> >         data.product_material = product_material;
> >         data.product_thread = product_thread;
> >         data.product_border = product_border;
> >         data.product_accessory = product_accessory;
> >         var csrf_token = $('#form_add_cart [name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
> >         data ["csrfmiddlewaretoken"] = csrf_token;
> >         var url = form.attr("action");
> >         $.ajax({
> >             url: url,
> >             type: 'POST',
> >             data: data,
> >             cache: true,
> >             success: function (data){
> >             },
> >             error: function(){
> >             },
> >         });
> >     }
> >
> >     var form = $('#form_add_cart');
> >     form.on('submit', function(e) {
> >         e.preventDefault();
> >
> >         var product_id = $('#submit_btn').data("product_id");
> >         var product_price = $('#submit_btn').data("product_price");
> >         var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
> >
> >         var e = document.getElementById("select");
> >         var product_material = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
> >         var e = document.getElementById("select_1");
> >         var product_thread = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
> >         var e = document.getElementById("select_2");
> >         var product_border = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
> >         var e = document.getElementById("select_3");
> >         var product_accessory = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
> >
> >         basketUpdating(product_id, quantity, product_material, product_thread, product_border, product_accessory)
> >     });
> > });
> > ```
>
> Сама форма:

```
<form action="{% url 'orders:basket_adding' %}" style="padding: 0;"
     class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 mb-4 align-items-stretch" method="post"
     id="form_add_cart">
                             {% csrf_token %}
                             <select class="select" id="select">
                                 {% for item in product_material_3 %}
                                     {% if item %}
                                         <option selected disabled>{{ item.color_title }}</option>
                                     {% endif %}
                                 {% endfor %}
                                 {% for item in product_material %}
                                     <option class="option" value="{{ item.color_title }}" data-product_material = "{{ item.color_title }}"
     id="material">
                                        {{ item.color_title }}
                                     </option>
                                 {% endfor %}
                             </select>
                             <select class="select_1" id="select_1">
                                 {% for item in product_thread_3 %}
                                     {% if item %}
                                         <option selected disabled>{{ item.color_title }}</option>
                                     {% endif %}
                                 {% endfor %}
                                 {% for item in product_thread %}
                                     <option class="option" value="{{ item.color_title }}" data-product_thread = "{{ item.color_title }}"
     id="thread">
                                         {{ item.color_title }}
                                     </option>
                                 {% endfor %}
                             </select>
                             <select class="select_2" id="select_2">
                                 {% for item in product_border_3 %}
                                     {% if item %}
                                         <option selected disabled>{{ item.color_title }}</option>
                                     {% endif %}
                                 {% endfor %}
                                 {% for item in product_border %}
                                     <option class="option" value="{{ item.color_title }}" data-product_border = "{{ item.color_title }}"
     id="border">
                                         {{ item.color_title }}
                                     </option>
                                 {% endfor %}
                             </select>
                             <select class="select_3" id="select_3">
                                 <option selected disabled>Не выбран</option>
                                 {% for item in accessory %}
                                        <option class="option" value="{{ item.accessory_title }}" data-product_accessory = "{{
     item.accessory_title }}" id="accessory">
                                             {{ item.accessory_title }}
                                         </option>
                                  {% endfor %}
                             </select>
                            <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
                                 <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity"  min="1" max="100">
                             </div>
                             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" id="submit_btn"
                                 data-product_id = "{{ product.id }}">
                                 Добавить в корзину
                             </button>
                         </form>
```

[image: ошибка на сайте]

Если локально на компьютере то все работает, а когда на сервер загрузил работало где 2 дня потом начала выходить ошибка, но при этом код не менял

Comment: Смотрите ошибку в логах сервера.

Comment: И хорошо бы закрыть [вот такие дирректории](https://iscarbox.ru/orders/basket_adding/) у вас все указано чтоб взломать сайт, кроме пароля на БД

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Спасибо, оказывается проблема была в базе данных.

Comment: @Greg-- Хорошо, спасибо